# Stagging matrix on Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have problems trying to stagger a 5x5 array. First I caused a null line to go to the last line of the array (it worked), then I tried to make a line that had the highest index stay below the one with a smaller index, but in the line:

```
if pivot_index[i] > pivot_index[line_aux] and line_aux < 5 and i < 5:
```

of the code, the compiler warns that the list index is out of range, but I do not know why (that's the problem), or how to solve it. The algorithm below follows:

```
import numpy as np
def search_pivot(L):
    if (np.nonzero(L)[0]).size == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return np.nonzero(L)[1][0]

def find_pivot_index(mat):
    pivot = []
    for i in range(5):
        pivot.append(search_pivot(np.array(mat[i])))
    return pivot

mat = np.matrix([[0,5,2,7,8],[0,0,4,14,16],[0,0,0,0,0],[2,6,10,16,22],[3,5,8,9,15]]).astype(float)
print("Original array:\n",mat,"\n")

pivot_index = find_pivot_index(mat)

line_aux = 0
for i in range(5): 
    line_aux = line_aux + 1
    if pivot_index[i] > pivot_index[line_aux] and line_aux < 5 and i < 5:
        m = mat.tolist()
        (m[i],m[linha_aux]) = (m[linha_aux],m[i])
        mat = np.matrix(m)
        pivot_index = find_pivot_index(mat)

print(mat,"\n")

line_aux = 0
for i in range(5):
    line_aux = line_aux + 1
    if pivot_index[i] == -1 and line_aux < 5 and i < 5:
        m = mat.tolist()
        (m[i],m[linha_aux]) = (m[linha_aux],m[i])
        mat = np.matrix(m)
        pivot_index = find_pivot_index(mat)

print(mat)
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, you might be interested in https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: (though, please avoid cross-posting, it would be better to post spanish code directly on es.stackoverflow.com instead)

Comment: Also, what is a staggered matrix, or to stagger an array? I don't recognise this as a standard term.

Comment: perhaps you mean "[jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array)"?

Comment: Sorry, I used Google Translator. My english is not good. But I want to triangularize the matrix 5x5 (cause an effect of stairs in the array)

Comment: A line that has the pivot at the highest index (in the line) must be below a line that has the pivot at a lower index. And null lines should be the last lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `and` operator in python is a [short-circuit boolean operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

This means that it will only proceed to evaluate the part to the right of `and` if the left side is `True`; if the left side is `False`, since this determines the outcome of the boolean operation completely, the right part does not get evaluated. This allows a programmer to perform a test on the left-hand side, before proceeding to a more 'risky' evaluation that could result in an error.

In your code, you have the test coming *after* the risky operation. You're checking if `linha_aux` (whatever that means) is less than 5 *after* you've attempted to index `pivos_indices` with a linha_aux of 5 already.  (this happens when i = 4, since the first line of your loop is to increment `linha_aux`.

Therefore:

- To "simply" avoid the 'out of index' error, put tests before risky operations:

  ```
  if line_aux < 5 and i < 5 and pivot_index[i] > pivot_index[line_aux]:
  ```
- You might want to consider if in fact you intended to increment `linha_aux` at the end of your loop rather than at the start, if that makes more sense to your algorithm; remember python arrays are 0-indexed

Comment: But I tried to change the variable, but the error persists. The goal is to make the matrix look like a ladder (or the effect of one): a row whose pivot has the highest index should be below a row that has a pivot with a lower index. Besides the null lines are always the last ones in the array. I've tried editing the code, I hope you understand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I understood your suggestion, I'll try.